# How to download file with curl from sftp server

Tags: xml, curl

I need to download `.xml` file for `SFTP server`.
When i used command `sftp://username:password@%ipaddress/ram//abc.xml`....it was working.

Requirement is to download for Multiple IP address.I tried to use it with curl to download via command
`curl -f -m 600 -o temp.xml sftp://username:password2%1/ram/abc.xml`.
`%1` is a text file which contains multiple iP address.

BUT it is not working....Could anybody suggest change in command ...thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can grab file securely from an `SSH` server using `SFTP`:

```
curl -u username sftp://server1.cyberciti.biz/path/to/file.txt
```

OR (note `~` means your `$HOME`)

```
curl -u vivek sftp://home1.cyberciti.biz/~/docs/resume.pdf
```

You can grab a file from an `SSH` server using `SCP` using a `private key` to authenticate.
 The syntax is:

```
curl -u username: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub scp://home1.cyberciti.biz/~/Videos/rhn_register.ogv
```

Where,

```
`-u username` - Specify the user name (and optional password) to use for server authentication.
`-u username:password` - Specify the user name (and optional password) to use for server authentication.
`--key ~/.ssh/id_rsa` - SSL or SSH private key file name. Allows you to provide your private key in this separate file.
`--pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` - SSH Public key file name. Allows you to provide your public key in this separate file.
scp://home1.cyberciti.biz/~/Videos/rhn_register.ogv - Use scp protocol and download file from my home server called home1.cyberciti.biz.
```

Comment: curl: (1) Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: @jliles - [How to enable SFTP Support in cURL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195545/how-to-enable-sftp-support-in-curl)